# Jquery: Keypress and Focus on a hidden DIV

Tags: jquery, html, focus, hidden, keypress

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".div").hide();
$(document).on('keypress paste', function() {
    $('form').focus();
    $(".div").show("fast");
});
});

Thanks to adeneo for the cleaner code.
```

**Description of use:**

The `div` element contains a hidden search form. When a key is pressed or the paste (ctrl+v) function is used on the page, a search box appears with the data inside.

**Problem:**

The first keypress works, but the first letter that is used as the keypress to unhide the `div` is lost in translation. So 'hello' becomes 'ello' in the search box.

The second works also, as long as you press ctrl+v twice. As above, it is using the first instance to call the `div` (I assume?).

**Help:**

Looking for any way to fix this code so it works as explained, or pointing in the right direction as to what code I should be using if the current code won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for the keypress-problem.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".div").hide();                     
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    if($('.div').is(':hidden')){
        $(".div").show("fast");
        $("#query").val($("#query").val()+String.fromCharCode(e.charCode));
        document.forms['form'].elements['query'].focus();
    }
});

$(document).bind('paste', function(e){
    console.log(e);
    document.forms['form'].elements['query'].focus();
    $(".div").show("fast");

});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Jkcj6/2/

Comment: Thanks Alex. That works perfectly. Is there any kind workaround for the paste function?